# Call a method in app.xaml.cs from ViewModel

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have some common code written in three ViewModels, which should be refactored. I have moved the code in a method in app.xaml.cs. Is this a right approach ? Now I have to call this method from the ViewModels, should I raise a custom event (from all ViewModels) and handle it on the app.xaml.cs ? If yes that would mean I have to create references of the ViewModels on the app.xaml.cs page (we are using Unity).
Does this seem right ? I am new to MVVM, any other suggestions ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: And what exactly is the common code responsible for..?

Comment: So, you moved common code from your ViewModels into the codebehind of a View???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you have "Cross cutting" challenges like where 2 totally separate objects need to communicate, an event style (publisher/subscriber) pattern works well.

If you are using Unity, then use the EventAggregator.

That way you can simply publish an event from your VM and have your app.xaml.cs listen for the event.

this way you wont have to let your VM know about app.xaml.cs.

Comment: We have done something similar, after web service call from both the VMs is completed, we raise events which are handled by app.xaml.cs to execute the same function.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't mentioned *what* the code is. Why is it in the App.xaml.cs file?
The fact that you need to call it from three different ViewModels would indicate that you should refactor it into either:

- a static helper type class
- a base class that your ViewModelss inherit from

The ViewModel's job is to hold and shape (or transform) data ready for display, but it shouldn't know about the display. Nor should it know about the contents of the App.xaml.cs, especially as your ViewModels may end up being in a totally different module or assembly to the App.xaml file.